# What is proper way to setup auth layer for CouchbaseLite (CBLListener and CBLReplication) for p2p database replication?

Tags: ios, couchbase-lite

I am trying to configure basic login / password authentication for p2p replication.
Replication works fine with no authentication. So I pretty sure my issue relates to authentication configuration.

`CBListener` configuration:

```
login = "my_login"
password = "my_password"

listener = CBLListener(manager: CBLManager.sharedInstance(), port: 55555)
listener.setBonjourName(netServiceName, type: netServiceType)
listener.readOnly = true
listener.setPasswords([login : password])
try! listener.start()
```

`CBLReplication` configuration:

```
let netService: NetService = ... // Got from NetServiceBrowserDelegate and NetServiceDelegate

let components = NSURLComponents()
components.scheme = "http"
components.host = netService.hostName
components.port = NSNumber(value: 55555)
components.path = "/" + database.name
components.user = login
components.password = password    

let newReplication = database.createPullReplication(components.url!)
newReplication.continuous = true
newReplication.start()
```

Here is what I am getting in Xcode console:

> CBLRestPuller[http://my_login:*****@Uladzimir-Papkos-iPad.local.:55555/sg_to_firstfoundry_net]: Going online
>
> CBLRestPuller[http://my_login:*****@Uladzimir-Papkos-iPad.local.:55555/sg_to_firstfoundry_net]: No local checkpoint; not getting remote one
>
> CBLRestPuller[http://my_login:*****@Uladzimir-Papkos-iPad.local.:55555/sg_to_firstfoundry_net] Progress: set active = 1
>
> CBLReplication[from http://my_login:*****@Uladzimir-Papkos-iPad.local.:55555/sg_to_firstfoundry_net]: active, progress = 0 / 0, err: (null)
>   nil
>
> CBLRestPuller[http://my_login:*****@Uladzimir-Papkos-iPad.local.:55555/sg_to_firstfoundry_net]: Reachability state = :reachable (20002), suspended=0
>
> : HTTP auth failed; sent Authorization: Basic bXlfbG9naW46bXlfcGFzc3dvcmQ=  ;  got WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="CouchbaseLite", qop="auth", nonce="69773230-683C-4DCC-AB40-A21527A1F911"
>
> CBLSocketChangeTracker[0x127d63810 sg_to_firstfoundry_net]: Can't connect, giving up: CBLHTTP[401, http://my_login:*****@Uladzimir-Papkos-iPad.local.:55555/sg_to_firstfoundry_net/_changes?feed=normal&heartbeat=300000&style=all_docs]<--NSURLError[-1013, http://my_login:*****@Uladzimir-Papkos-iPad.local.:55555/sg_to_firstfoundry_net/_changes?feed=normal&heartbeat=300000&style=all_docs]
>
> CBLRestPuller[http://my_login:*****@Uladzimir-Papkos-iPad.local.:55555/sg_to_firstfoundry_net]: ChangeTracker stopped; error=CBLHTTP[401, http://my_login:*****@Uladzimir-Papkos-iPad.local.:55555/sg_to_firstfoundry_net/_changes?feed=normal&heartbeat=300000&style=all_docs]<--NSURLError[-1013, http://my_login:*****@Uladzimir-Papkos-iPad.local.:55555/sg_to_firstfoundry_net/_changes?feed=normal&heartbeat=300000&style=all_docs]

I think the most important log here is this line:

> : HTTP auth failed; sent Authorization:
>   Basic bXlfbG9naW46bXlfcGFzc3dvcmQ=  ;  got WWW-Authenticate: Digest
>   realm="CouchbaseLite", qop="auth",
>   nonce="69773230-683C-4DCC-AB40-A21527A1F911"

Alternatively I tried to use `CBLAuthenticator` instead of injecting login/password into url. Still doesn't work, however I am getting different error messages in log:
What is changed:

```
// Added:
newReplication.authenticator = CBLAuthenticator.basicAuthenticator(withName: login, password: password)

// Removed:
components.user = login 
components.password = password
```

Here is what I am getting in Xcode console after updating the code:

> CBLRestPuller[http://Uladzimir-Papkos-iPad.local.:55555/sg_to_firstfoundry_net]: Going online
>
> CBLRestPuller[http://Uladzimir-Papkos-iPad.local.:55555/sg_to_firstfoundry_net] Progress: set active = 1
>
> CBLRestPuller[http://Uladzimir-Papkos-iPad.local.:55555/sg_to_firstfoundry_net]: Successfully logged in!
>
> RemoteRequest: Added Authorization header for CBLPasswordAuthorizer[my_login/****]
>
> CBLRemoteJSONRequest[GET http://Uladzimir-Papkos-iPad.local.:55555/sg_to_firstfoundry_net/_local/b3f625c9bddabfb59ee49d78f3bb484a5876b486]: Starting...
>
> DEALLOC CBLRemoteLogin[http://Uladzimir-Papkos-iPad.local.:55555/sg_to_firstfoundry_net]
>   2017-02-20 16:51:28.335 Union Dev[1922:1702832] RemoteRequest: CBLRemoteSession starting CBLRemoteJSONRequest[GET http://Uladzimir-Papkos-iPad.local.:55555/sg_to_firstfoundry_net/_local/b3f625c9bddabfb59ee49d78f3bb484a5876b486]
>
> Sync: CBLReplication[from http://Uladzimir-Papkos-iPad.local.:55555/sg_to_firstfoundry_net]: active, progress = 0 / 0, err: (null)
>   nil
>
> CBLRestPuller[http://Uladzimir-Papkos-iPad.local.:55555/sg_to_firstfoundry_net]: Reachability state = :reachable (20002), suspended=0
>
> RemoteRequest: Got challenge for CBLRemoteJSONRequest[GET http://Uladzimir-Papkos-iPad.local.:55555/sg_to_firstfoundry_net/_local/b3f625c9bddabfb59ee49d78f3bb484a5876b486]: method=NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPDigest, err=(null)
>
> RemoteRequest:     challenge: (phase 3) continueWithoutCredential
>
> Sync: CBLRestPuller[http://Uladzimir-Papkos-iPad.local.:55555/sg_to_firstfoundry_net]: Server is (null)
>
> RemoteRequest: CBLRemoteJSONRequest[GET http://Uladzimir-Papkos-iPad.local.:55555/sg_to_firstfoundry_net/_local/b3f625c9bddabfb59ee49d78f3bb484a5876b486]: Got response, status 401
>
> CBLRemoteJSONRequest[GET http://Uladzimir-Papkos-iPad.local.:55555/sg_to_firstfoundry_net/_local/b3f625c9bddabfb59ee49d78f3bb484a5876b486]: Got error CBLHTTP[401, "unauthorized", http://Uladzimir-Papkos-iPad.local.:55555/sg_to_firstfoundry_net/_local/b3f625c9bddabfb59ee49d78f3bb484a5876b486]
>
> Sync: CBLRestPuller[http://Uladzimir-Papkos-iPad.local.:55555/sg_to_firstfoundry_net]: Error fetching last sequence: CBLHTTP[401, "unauthorized", http://Uladzimir-Papkos-iPad.local.:55555/sg_to_firstfoundry_net/_local/b3f625c9bddabfb59ee49d78f3bb484a5876b486]
>
> Sync: CBLRestPuller[http://Uladzimir-Papkos-iPad.local.:55555/sg_to_firstfoundry_net] Progress: set error = CBLHTTP[401, "unauthorized", http://Uladzimir-Papkos-iPad.local.:55555/sg_to_firstfoundry_net/_local/b3f625c9bddabfb59ee49d78f3bb484a5876b486]

Could anybody point me to place where I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you try using an authenticator on the replicator explicitly instead of setting the username and password through the URL?  Add this line before you start the replication -> `newReplication.authenticator = [CBLAuthenticator basicAuthenticatorWithName: login password: password];` (sorry for the Obj-C syntax)

Comment: Also this question is here too now:  https://forums.couchbase.com/t/what-is-proper-way-to-setup-auth-layer-for-couchbaselite-cbllistener-and-cblreplication-for-p2p-database-replication/11838 so this SO question will likely remain unanswered if it gets answered on the forums)

Comment: @borrrden, thanks for response. Yes I tried your suggestion, getting different messages in log, but still authentication doesn't work. I updated question with more details about solution you suggested.

Comment: @borrrden, I posted this question to couchbase forum as well to increase chance to solve this issue. I will post answer here if I get answer on forum and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having conversation with Couchbase engineers it was decided that the best solution here is to enable secure http connection, since it doesn't make sense to send login / password through insecure http request.

The easiest (not most secure) way to enable https is to do next:

```
// Change url to https
components.scheme = "https"

// Inject self-signed generated on the fly certificate into CBLListener
try listener.setAnonymousSSLIdentityWithLabel("use_any_string_here")
```

More information about configuring https connection for p2p replication is available [here](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-ios/wiki/SSL).